# Dyck's Theorem via a Birational Transformation

Tags: birational-geometry, torus

In our paper, at Journal of Geometry and Graphics, v. 20, n. 1 (2016), Danny Maienschein and I showed that some well-known transformations of the real projective plane (defined almost everywhere), based on a fixed triangle, are part of a continuous group of such transformations. This was accomplished (1) using a (new?) birational transformation that blows up the triangle vertices, and collapses its circumcircle and the line at infinity, and then (2) reinterpreting the well-known transformations as just reflections of a real torus.

To our surprise, this birational transformation also demonstrates Dyck's Theorem about homeomorphic surfaces (P#P#P and T#P), as mentioned in the paper's introduction. Are there any references to using birational transformations for demonstrating such homeomorphisms? Any other thoughts or questions?